# steering axis of carlike robot with teb_local_planner

Tags: ros, simulation, teb-local-planner, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have an car-like robot and use the new [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) for driving. What is missing in the documentation is the question of the steering axis (front or rear), resp. where /base_link sits on the robot. As a first step, I modified [teb_local_planner_tutorials](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/launch/robot_carlike_in_stage.launch) to reflect our robot model and world. In contrast to the original *robot_carlike_in_stage* launch example where */base_link* sits on the rear axis, our /base_link frame resides in the center of the **front** axis (as usual for this robot model). Accordingly our (rotation) origin is at */base_link* and therefore in the front and not in the back, which is also modeled in the stage parameters of the robot model.

The result of running the stage simulation is, that the car seems to steer with the back rather than the front axis. In any case, it looks wrong. Does the *teb_local_planner* only support car-like robots that steer with the rear axis? How do I have to model the robot to reflect steering with the front axis?

EDIT:
The wheelbase parameter is described as

> The distance between the drive shaft and steering axle. The value might be negative for back-wheeled robots.

So for our robot, drive shaft is in the front, as well as steering axle and */base_link*. So wheelbase according to the description is 0, but the planner does not produce reasonable output with that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237035/steering-axis-of-carlike-robot-with-teb_local_planner/) by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed, the parameter definition for the wheelbase is misleading.
The wheelbase is defined as the distance between the rear and front axle.
However, the wheelbase parameter is only used in case you are sending commands to a base controller dealing with a *modified Twist message* such as stage in the *car* mode (see Section 2.2.1 [here](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots)).
Which one of the axles is the actual drive shaft is not relevant for the teb_local_planner, since we ignore friction, slipping etc.

Regarding your navigation setup and questions:

First of all, the planner should work with both types of car-like robots (steering with the front or rear axle).
But you need to revise your model in order to make it work.
The car-like robot is considered as uni-cycle model with additional constraints (limiting turning radius etc.).
Thus it is important that the center of rotation is defined properly by the location of the *base-link* frame.
You are defining the frame at the center of the steering axle, but this is not the actual center of rotation of the robot.
Refer to [1] for mathematical details. Here you can also find the theory on representing a car-like robot as uni-cycle model. Section 2.2. of the [car-like robot tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots) shows an example image for robots with front-steering. The *base_link* frame must be located at the center of the **rear**-axle in order to work properly with the planner (accordingly, a robot with rear-steering requires *base_link* to be located at the front-axle).

In summary, the following steps should be performed:

- Front steering: locate *base_link* at the center of the rear-axle (rear-steering: *base_link* at front-axle)
- Set the desired minimum turning radius `min_turning_radius` (either try it out using rqt_reconfigure or calculate the value using the relations of transforming a car-like robot to a uni-cycle model: `max_steering_angle=atan(wheelbase/min_turning_radius)` (-> solve w.r.t. `min_turning_radius`).
- Depending on the base controller, you need to convert the twist message from the navigation stack to a message containing the linear velocity and the steering angle. Stage requires a twist message in which `angular.z` corresponds to the steering angle. In that case, the teb_local_planner provides an internal conversion if `cmd_angle_instead_rotvel` is activated. Only then, `wheelbase` is taken into account. The conversion is performed according to the relation mentioned above:

  `steering_angle = atan(wheelbase*omega/v) if v!=0`

  `steering_angle = 0 if v==0`

  However, sometimes it is preferable to set the `steering_angle` to the previous value for v=0. But in that case, you might implement your own small conversion script that subscribes to `cmd_vel`.

---

[1] [S. LaValle, Planning Algorithms, Cambridge University Press, 2006: Chapter 13](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/)

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2016-06-16**:
Thanks! Just one detail: With base_link you mean the *robot_frame_id* tf param (global costmap), right? So from move_base/teb_local_planner it should work (despite Stage issues) by introducing a new frame on the rear axis and setting this one as robot_frame_id. Or does it have to be base_link itself

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-06-16**:
Exactly, but the *robot_frame_id* specified for the local costmap. You should be able to introduce a new virtual frame as long as I haven't missed anything in the code ;-)